# _pickle.UnpicklingError: unpickling stack underflow while using binary files

Tags: python, pickle, binaryfiles, file-handling, python-idle

I wrote this python program.

```
import pickle
def Write():
    f=open("StudentDetails.dat",'wb')
    while True:
        r=int(input("Enter Roll no.: "))
        n=input("Enter Name: ")
        m=int(input("Enter Marks: "))
        record=[r,n,m]
        pickle.dump(record,f)
        ch=input("Do you want to enter more records (Y/N)")
        if ch in 'Nn':
            break
    f.close()

def Read():
    f=open("StudentDetails.dat",'rb')
    try:
        while True:
            rec=pickle.load(f)
            print(rec)
    except EOFError:
        pass
    f.close()
    
def Update():
    f=open("StudentDetails.dat",'rb+')
    rollno=int(input("Enter roll no whose marks you want to update: "))
    try:
        while True:
            pos=f.tell()
            rec=pickle.load(f)
            if rec[0]==rollno:
                um=int(input("Enter updated marks: "))
                rec[2]=um
                f.seek(pos)
                pickle.dump(rec,f)
                break
    except EOFError:
        pass
    f.close()
    
Write()
Read()
Update()
Read()
```

But it is giving me the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\updt.py", line 45, in <module>
    Read()
  File "C:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\updt.py", line 19, in Read
    rec=pickle.load(f)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: unpickling stack underflow
```

I think the program works correctly in pycharm but gives error in IDLE. How can this be possible? Besides I am unable to correct the error. So any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Writing a new pickle into the middle of the file is a completely unworkable approach to updating your data.  The new pickle is most likely not going to be exactly the same length as the old one; there will be a fragment of the old record left behind if the new record is shorter, or you'll partially overwrite the next record if the new record is longer.  What you really need here is a *database*, that handles such details for you.

Comment: Line 45 is the second Read call, after Update.  Put a comment such as `# Read update.` to aid debugging. I suspect that any difference between runs is due to a difference of the unrecorded input.  For development and debugging, make your program reproducible by reading data included in the program.  For instance, use a list of strings instead of input().  Also use io.StringIO instead of external files.  To eliminate IDEs as a bug source, run your program directly with Python.  Also, multiple python installs can cause differences.